# Stop animation of a movie clip in flash Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-engine, movieclip, flash-cs6

I am new to Flash..(not very new) and i'd like to ask a question.
I just made (work in progress) a game in which we have to shoot people falling from sky.
I was going to make enemies but i thought to make some effect..like shooting.
I made an effect in which, where i click, a new child is made and its a movie clip animation of explosion. But i am unable to stop the animation. It continues to loop. I tried stop();
in the last frame of the symbol but then it would not even add the child on the screen.
Here is the .fla file :-

http://www.mediafire.com/download/lwol38o4454sphp/Game.fla

and here is the code :-

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;

addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveturret);
Mouse.hide();
var firegun:boom22 = new boom22();

function moveturret (e:Event)

{
    aim.x = mouseX
    aim.y = mouseY
    var differenceX = mouseX - turret.x;
    var differenceY = mouseY - turret.y;
    var radianToDegrees = (Math.PI/180);
    turret.rotation = Math.atan2(differenceY, differenceX)/radianToDegrees;
}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fire);

function fire (e:MouseEvent)

{
    firegun.x = mouseX
    firegun.y = mouseY
    addChild(firegun);
}
```

Comment: `removeChild(firegun);` after a timer

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener to check for when the clip is done playing, then have it remove itself.

Maybe something like:

```
// within your fire() event handler
addChild(firegun);
firegun.gotoAndPlay(1); // just in case
firegun.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, removeSelfWhenDone, false, 0, true);



// then new method:
// on every frame tick, check if last frame is reached, if so, remove it from it's parent (which would be the stage)
function removeSelfWhenDone(inputEvent:Event):void {
    var clip:MovieClip = (MovieClip) (inputEvent.target);
    if(clip.currentFrame == clip.totalFrames){
        // also remove the event listener (as it gets added again later)
        clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, removeSelfWhenDone, false);
        clip.parent.removeChild(clip);
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Error #1006: removeSelfWhenDone is not a function.
 at Game_fla::MainTimeline/removeSelfWhenDone()

this is what i get when i do it....

Comment: pls try to download the fla so you can see what is on my screen.

Comment: I won't be able to open it as I'm using cs5. But the purpose is to add an event frame listener to the movieclip itself that monitors when it is done playing.

Comment: well.. i tried to modify the code and try but it didn't work, sry.